# Close Informix connection in scheduler

Tags: database, informix

I built a scheduler who can get data from Informix database. My scheduler is triggered every 30 seconds. But I have a question about the connection close. Do you recommend me to close the connection to Informix at the end of the script then do the connection again 30 seconds after ? Or let the connection open every time then I have to connect just once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

It depends on how you've written the scheduler code.  If your code can or does make use of prepared statements and can reuse those statements, then you save the cost of re-preparing those statements if you keep the connection open.

However, the server is good at handling queries.  And 30 seconds is quite a long time in some respects — though obviously not very long in others.  Establishing one connection every 30 seconds isn't going to stress the system.

If your code is clean and carefully written, you won't have memory leaks so keeping the connection open won't matter.  If your code is not carefully written, you may have memory leaks (it depends partly on the language(s) you're using), and maybe re-establishing the connection is better.

On the whole, closing the connection reduces the chances for problems.  If you're not sure, close it.

Comment: Thank you for your pretty answer. I wrote it in Python3. I insert data to MongoDB and I call web services to add data to another server. I didn't see memory leaks. The first init is a big bulk insert but the other times I will add just 1 - 3 max (and often 0) items to mongodb because I check I have already the object. But when I see your answer I think there is no advantage to keep the connection open.